# Passbook isn't hitting .NET web service

Tags: passbook

I created a .pkpass file and downloaded it to my iPhone. I am able to add it to Passbook app but the problem is that it simply won't hit my webservice. The .pkpass file has webServiceURL(https) and authenticationToken keys. The device logs on Mac shows these entries when I add the pass to passbook app:

> [Notice] Too frequent rssi event from driver, ignoring
>
> [Error] OCSPSingleResponse: now>nextUpdate
>
> [Notice] BG Application : Not Present, BG Daemon: Present, Daemons:
>   apsd networkd
>
> [Warning] BTM: attaching to BTServer
>
> [Warning] Error retrieving passes and catalog (2 retries remaining):
>   The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 4097)
>
> [Warning] Pass library connection interrupted.
>
> PassbookUIService [Warning] Pass library connection interrupted.
>
> passd No sandbox extension for cached ubiquity container failed
>
> [warning] Launch Services: Registerimg unknown app identifier
>   com.apple.Passkit failed
>
> [warning] Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier
>   com.apple.Passkit

Can someone tell what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing the pass on an iPhone or inside the simulator?

Comment: I should clarify - have you tried viewing the logs when installing the pass on an iPhone or inside the simulator? Whilst OS X will display the pass, it certainly doesn't install it, so I wouldn't expect the logs to show anything.

Comment: On Iphone, I tried clicking on the "add" button  from the preview screen and noticed it was added inside the passbook app. Is this different to pass installation? The above log is an extract from Xcode->Windows->Devices->Logs. I got these logs when I connected the phone to the Mac and clicked on the "add" button.

Comment: Would you mind sending the papas file to me? I can take a look if you wish.

Comment: Sorry Tomas. I wish I could but I won't be able to share it for security reasons. However, I tried creating a generic pass from www.passsource.com using iPhone simulator and used Wireshark to capture requests in the background. I noticed there was network traffic up until the point I created and previewed the pass on Safari. After this, there was absolutely no network activity neither when I clicked on the add button nor when I pulled down on the back of the card to perform a manual update. The Passbook app doesn't seem to do any background tasks at all. Is there any setting I need to change?

Comment: BTW, I noticed the below system logs:   1.BTM: failed to attach with error 9
 2. Error looking up items (null) in store: Cannot connect to iTunes Store' Does these mean anything?